# How are attachment styles linked to personality disorders

Tags: developmental-psychology, personality-disorder, correlation, dsm

There are three different patterns of behavior in the so called strange situation in which the caregiver leaves the infant for a while and a stranger comes in the room. These behavioral patterns are than classified in three attachment styles: secure, resistant and avoidant.

Is there any quantitative research that links the early attachment styles with the probability of certain personality disorders?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classification of Attachment Styles](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/4382/classification-of-attachment-styles)

Comment: Also look at a book called *Disorganized Attachment* by David Shemmings and Yvonne Shemmings. I attended a talk by David Shemmings on the subject where disorganized attachment issues can lead to mental health issues later in life.

Comment: My question is a little bit more specific. I am looking for studies that show the correlation between specific attachment styles and specific personality disorders.